# Series Divergence Proof

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, divergent-series

I'm asked to decide whether the following series converges or diverges:

$$1-\frac{3}{4}+\frac{4}{6}-\frac{5}{8}+\frac{6}{10}-\frac{7}{12}+\cdots$$

So I first looked at $(a_n)=\frac{n+1}{2n}$. Then by separating this into $a_n=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{1}{n}$, we can say that since we know $\frac{1}{n}\rightarrow0$, then $a_n \rightarrow \frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}\cdot0=\frac{1}{2}$. Then since $(a_n)$ does not converge to $0$, we know that $\sum a_n$ diverges by the divergence test. 
Now I'm stuck. How do I use this to account for the alternating sequence $(-1)^n a_n$? Is there a theorem that would help?

Thanks!

Comment: Not converging does not mean diverging.

Comment: not converging = diverging.

Comment: I thought if a sequence does not converge to 0, then its corresponding series diverges

Comment: Ok, may be it's a matter of definition. The definition I use for divergence is, for any positive real number $R$, $\exists N$ such that $|\sum _{n=1}^N a_n| >R $.

Comment: That is not the standard definition I've ever seen,  @mastrok . That'd be for a sequence that diverges to $\infty$,  but you can have a divergent sequence that oscillates as well, like this one

Comment: By the way, there's a difference between "diverging" and "diverging to infinity." For example, the series $1-1+1-1+\dotsb$ diverges, but doesn't go to infinity. A divergent series is any series whose partial sums don't have a (finite) limit.

Comment: I changed 1-$\frac{3}{4}$+$\frac{4}{6}$-$\frac{5}{8}$+$\frac{6}{10}$-$\frac{7}{12}$... to $\displaystyle 1-\frac{3}{4}+\frac{4}{6}-\frac{5}{8}+\frac{6}{10}-\frac{7}{12}+\cdots$ and in other respects changed some MathJax code to standard usage.  ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that, indeed I learnt diverging and diverging to infinity long time ago. For my background, we have given diverging but not to infinity another name instead of also calling it divergent. Sorry for messing that up.

Comment: @Laura. As far as convergence for an alternating series is concerned, it needs to meet 2 criteria: 1) The infinite term must go to zero (which it doesn't in your example). 2) Ultimately, every next term must be smaller (in absolute terms) than the previous term, so when knocking of the negatives, the sequence must be decreasing. This is how it is for an alternating series in a NUTshell.

Answer (score 2):

It's a necessary (but not sufficient) criterion for any series to converge that the sequence converges to $0$.   If it's an alternating series in which the absolute values are monotonically decreasing to $0$, it's also sufficient for convergence.

In this case, since your sequence does not converge to $0$,  you're done; it diverges.  (It doesn't matter if it's alternating or not.)

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you let $c_n=(-1)^n a_n$.

As you've shown, $|c_n|=a_n\not\to0\;,$ so $c_n\not\to0$ also $\;\;$since $c_n\to0\iff|c_n|\to0$.

Therefore you can conclude that $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}c_n$ diverges by the Divergence Test.

Comment: I haven't yet been taught that $c_n$$\rightarrow$0 if and only if $\mid$$c_n$$\mid$$\rightarrow$0

Comment: @Laura One way to see this is to use $|c_n-0|<\epsilon$ for $n\ge N$ iff $||c_n|-0|<\epsilon$ for $n\ge N$ since $|c_n|=||c_n||$

Answer (score 0):

I would like to
abuse terminology somewhat
by saying that
this series
"multi-converges",
because there are
a finite number of values
$v_k$
and a finite set of disjoint sequences
$u_k(n)$ which together make up
the non-negative integers
 such that
$\sum_{i=0}^{u_k(n)} a_i
\to v_k
$.

In this case,
$k=2$
and the sequences
are the even and odd integers.
It is not hard to show that
$\sum_{i=0}^{2n} a_i
$
and
$\sum_{i=0}^{2n+1} a_i
$
each converge
as $n \to \infty$,
but to separate values.

Since
$a_n 
= (-1)^n\frac{n+2}{2n+2}
$,

$\begin{array}\\
a_{2n}+a_{2n+1}
&=\frac{2n+2}{4n+2}-\frac{2n+3}{4n+4}\\
&=\frac12(\frac{2n+2}{2n+1}-\frac{2n+3}{2n+2})\\
&=\frac12(\frac{(2n+2)^2-(2n+1)(2n+3)}{(2n+1)(2n+2)})\\
&=\frac12(\frac{4n^2+8n+4-(4n^2+8n+3)}{(2n+1)(2n+2)})\\
&=\frac12(\frac{1}{(2n+1)(2n+2)})\\
\end{array}
$

and

$\begin{array}\\
a_{2n-1}+a_{2n}
&=-\frac{2n+1}{4n}+\frac{2n+2}{4n+2}\\
&=\frac12(-\frac{2n+1}{2n}+\frac{2n+2}{2n+1})\\
&=\frac12(\frac{-(2n+1)^2+(2n)(2n+2)}{2n(2n+1)})\\
&=\frac12(\frac{-(4n^2+4n+1)+(4n^2+4n}{2n(2n+1)})\\
&=\frac12(\frac{-1}{2n(2n+1)})\\
\end{array}
$

and the sum of each of these
converges
since they are both
$O(1/n^2)$.